# How to transform array of empty strings into empty array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects:

```
const arr = [{name: ''}]
```

I want to map over this array and, if `name` value is `""` (empty string), I want the result to be an empty array `[]`.

If it has values, then I want the result to be an array with the values (eg. `["Rick"]`

I've tried to have a fallback value but the result is still `[""]`

My attempt:

```
const result = arr.map(a => a.name) || []
```

Actual result: `[""]`

Desired result: `[]`

Comment: Filter the array first `result = arr.filter(a => a.name).map(a => a.name) || []`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Filter the array first

```js
const arrWithNamesAndEmpty = [{name: ''}, {name: 'Hello'}];
const arrWithEmptyNames = [{name: ''}];

function removeEmptyNamesAndPluckName(arr) {
  return arr.filter(a => a.name).map(a => a.name);
} 

console.log({
  arrWithNamesAndEmpty: removeEmptyNamesAndPluckName(arrWithNamesAndEmpty),
  arrWithEmptyNames: removeEmptyNamesAndPluckName(arrWithEmptyNames)
})
```

The above solution is the simplest to read but it's not the most performant. If you find yourself in a bottleneck, the `reduce` approach suggested by [@joopmacroop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67887548/227299) is the faster version. Stay away from the [`flatMap` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67887809/227299), it's an order of magnitude slower on Chrome, Safari and Edge and it's also not as easy to understand.

See https://jsbench.me/0lkpo4lsu4/1

Table below in Ops/sec **More is faster**

| Browser | Filter + Map | Reduce | flatMap |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chrome | 2,525,726 | 3,800,221 | 170,365 |
| Firefox | 836,111 | 957,237 | 598,365 |
| Safari | 477,305 | 2,089,445 | 367,878 |
| Edge | 2,790,834 | 4,819,590 | 217,948 |

Comment: This answer will loop 2 times the same array which is not necessary.

Comment: @ikhvjs [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/1691:_Optimizationhttps://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/1691:_Optimization) You should make your code easier to read instead of optimizing it before it's necessary. Optimizations make the code harder to read/maintain.

Comment: Just saw your updated answer. Upvoted for your effort to show the Benchmark!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use reduce, to filter and map at the same time. (loops only once)

```js
var arr = [{name: ''}, {name:'rick'}];
var res = arr.reduce((v,p)=>{ p.name && v.push(p.name); return v; },[]);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: For filtering and mapping in a single pass, I prefer `flatMap`. Here it would be: `arr.flatMap(v => v.name ? [v.name] : [])`

Comment: I think using `reduce` makes it harder to read, you are not really `reducing` something. Semantically, it's filtering the array and then mapping it so calling those methods makes the code easier to follow. I would only use something like this if this was a performance bottleneck, but I'm not even sure this would be faster

Comment: @spender may i know why you are wrapping `v.name` with array? . I think its only ignore the empty `array`. its have any specific reason ?

Comment: @prasanth flatMap will concat all of the arrays that are returned by the selector function into a single array. So a one item array's item will end up in the output and the empty array won't have any item put into the output.

Comment: @spender Note that the `flatMap` solution is the slowest of all three and it's not as comprehensible as `filter().map()` I'd use `filter().map()` when performance is not a concern and `reduce` when hitting a bottleneck. [See my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67887434/227299) for performance details.

Comment: @JuanMendes A good write-up indeed. My `flatMap` habit stems from TypeScript where I use it on, for instance `Array<SomeType|undefined>`. Here the return-type of `arr.filter(x => x!=null)` remains  `Array<SomeType|undefined>` ***but*** `arr.flatMap(x => x!=null?[x]:[])` is `Array<SomeType>`. Not "performant", but a good way to force the type.

Answer (score 1):

You could do [Array#flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) for single loop

```js
var arr = [{name: ''}];
var res = arr.flatMap(a=>a.name ? a.name :[])

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Please see the updated accepted answer. flatMap actually is not well efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [{name: ''}, {name: 'Rick'}]

const res = arr.filter(obj => obj.name).map(obj => obj.name)

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Why post an answer that is identical to an existing answer?

Comment: Sorry, but your answer was not visible when i started posting...